# Why is it discouraged to use absolute paths in Shiny includeScript()?

Tags: r, shiny

From `?includeScript`:

> path:
>    The path of the file to be included. It is highly recommended to use a relative path (the base path being the Shiny application
>   directory), not an absolute path.

But the function `includeScript` reads the script with `readLines`, it doesn't somehow include the path in HTML so that it would get loaded client side (which would obviously be bad). So I don't see why I shouldn't use an absolute path. In particular, my application would be `includeScript(system.file("js/blub.js", package="mypackage"))` (and my Shiny app is in objects, not sourced) so to me this is the nice way to do it. Am I wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you know the difference between an absolute and a relative path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You wouldn't want to use an absolute path as, if you moved the application to another system, it might stop working---if the directory structure on the systems differed.

But, it doesn't look like you are using an absolute path. An absolute path is something like `/home/meow/blub.js`.

Comment: ```system.file()``` returns an absolute path.
```system.file("SOURCES.ts", package = "stats")```

Comment: But I think I get the idea now. My path is technically an absolute path but functionally a relative path. 

I originally thought they wanted to use relative paths because of the same reason you usually want to use relative paths in HTML and such; which was not the case.

Thanks!

Comment: Correct. `system.file()` will respond to the local conditions.